# How can I put a newline in my zsh prompt without causing terminal redraw issues?

Tags: command-line, osx-snow-leopard, zsh, prompt

I'm trying to fix a minor (but annoying) issue with my zsh prompt. The problem I'm seeing is that when I'm using a terminal in a GUI OS environment (for example, Terminal.app or iTerm 2 on OS X 10.7.2) and resize the terminal window, the terminal is redrawn with extra prompts.

I've reproduced the issue on a clean .zshrc that contains the following:

```
export PROMPT=">
"
```

To be clear, that's a two-line file. There is a literal newline in the string, which I've read in several ([admittedly old](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/1998/msg00911.html)) places is the way to go. This works until I resize the terminal window, at which point I end up with duplicate prompt strings. For example if I open a new window, I see (`*` being used a placeholder for my cursor):

```
Last login: Wed Jan 25 19:05:06 on ttys000
>
*
```

Then when I resize the window, making it shorter, I end up with:

```
Last login: Wed Jan 25 19:05:06 on ttys000
>
>
>
>
*
```

The number of extra prompt printouts seems roughly proportional to how much I change the window size -- usually vertically. If I remove the newline from the prompt string, the problem goes away.

I've tried various things, like `$(print ">\n")`, or trying to wrap the newline in `%{%}`. I'm assuming this has to do with the fact that newline confuses whatever is drawing w.r.t how long the prompt string actually is, or something. Is this problem fixable or do I just have to live with it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This problem is due to how ZSH reprints the promt on resize events and has also annoyed me before. The solution is to make `$PROMPT` single-line and print the first line of the prompt using a precmd.

So in your example that would simply be:

```
precmd() { print ">" }
export PROMPT=""
```

or for a more sophisticated example with prompt expansion in the print statement use the `-rP` parameters:

```
precmd() { print -rP "%~" }
export PROMPT="%# "
```

If you have more than one precmd registered you need to use `add-zsh-hook precmd` (see `man zshcontrib`).

Comment: For newbies like myself, you can see what -rP means here:  http://www.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_17.html.  It appears that `print` is a ZSH-specific command, and Googling "linux print" doesn't give you very good results.

Comment: `print` is part of zsh.  You can see the help for it in `man zshbuiltins`.  Bash has its own equivalent, but I'm not sure they're compatible.

Answer (score 47):

How about something like this:

```
NEWLINE=$'\n'
PROMPT="Line1${NEWLINE}LINE2"
```

Comment: I like this solution better than the accepted answer. it is more portable, and allows me to maintain the same script between my zsh and bash environments

Comment: This solution worked better for me.

Comment: Bravo. Nice and simple. If you just want to, say, prepend a newline to the existing prompt, you can `PROMPT="$NEWLINE$PROMPT"`.

Comment: ...or as a single assignment `PROMPT=$'Line1\nLINE2'`, or if parameter expansion is needed `PROMPT="$(uname)"$'\n'"$CPUTYPE"` etc., or use an intermediate array `lines=(Line1 LINE2); PROMPT="${(F)lines}"`

Comment: This solution is much more cleaner.

I was searching for why `\n` didn't work inside `"`s but apparently when added inside `'`it works. Some ZSH quirk is it?